# "This year might look and feel a bit different" or "This year might look and feel differently"

Tags: grammar

> This year might look and feel a bit different, we will all be superheroes together.
>
> This year might look and feel differently, we will all be superheroes together.

Which one is correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: The second gets into grammar issues I just don't want to go into. So, the first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show simpler examples:

1. This year looks and feels different.
2. This year looks and feels differently.

Sentence 1 is correct. Both "looks" and "feels" are linking verbs in this context, connecting "this year" with the predicate adjective "different".  The meaning is approximately "This year seems different.", which is close to "This year is different."

The word "differently" is an adverb, and it doesn't fit the meaning of the sentence, so sentence 2 is not correct.

Your original sentence 1 is still a type of run-on sentence called a comma splice. It can be corrected by splitting it into two sentences, or by inserting a colon:

> This year might look and feel a bit different. We will all be superheroes together.
> This year might look and feel a bit different: we will all be superheroes together.

Answer (score 0):

1. "This year might look and feel a bit different, we will all be superheroes together."
2. "This year might look and feel differently, we will all be superheroes together."

'Different' is more natural.

Both examples have comma splice problem and require a conjunction.  The choice depends on the intended meaning.

One possibility is as follows:

'This year might look and feel a bit different; nevertheless, we will all be superheroes together.'